# How do i build react-native application

Tags: react-native

i just created a new react-native app using `npx create-react-native-app myapp` which was successfully created. but when i try to build it using `gradlew assembleRelease`, i get this error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Failed to find Platform SDK with path: platforms;android-30

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.8/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 43s
```

it appears like teres a gradle problem. how do i fix it?

Comment: make sure you have android 30

Comment: what is android 30 and how do i get it

Comment: Android 30 means the api version of Androifd. According the Internet is means Android 11 in common speech.

Comment: pianoman, you didnt get my question. ive run react native before, and all installations are done